# Подскажите компонент(ы) для вывода .doc и .pdf файлов на веб странице

Tags: doc

Необходимо отображать содержимое .doc и .pdf файлов прямо на веб странице в некоем отдельном виджете. Важно, чтобы файл отображался как есть — со всем форматированием итп. Подскажите пожалуйста, существуют ли готовые компоненты для этого? Как-то сходу найти не получилось.

Просьба сторонние проекты, такие как гугл-документы не предлагать.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчет просмотра .doc, то существует [Microsoft Office Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/ru-ru/web-apps/).

Comment: А чтобы без регистраций? Просто хочу подключить к одному проекту своему и не хотелось бы затруднять их регистрироваться ещё где нибудь.

Comment: А там и так без регистрации. На Mail.ru стоит такое приложение и регистрироваться не надо, просто открыл и все.

Comment: Прости, не могу там найти его. Не поделишься линком?

Comment: Как я понял, чтобы начать работать с Microsoft Office Web Apps тебе надо зарегистрироваться и скачать. Ссылку я дал в ответе. Чтобы посмотреть как выглядит он на Mail.ru давай E-mail я покажу.

Comment: Ну как бы мыло давать не особо хочется, так как тут мало ли кто сидит, потом от спама не оберусь
Может как то иначе можешь показать? Раз это приложение, то просто кинь ссылку на него.
Спасибо

Comment: Приложение работает только в почте. Ну я так думаю). Поэтому. Вот нашел [скрин](http://www.livebusiness.ru/phpthumb/cache/9/9b/9be/9bef/phpThumb_cache_src9bef3ce1dfffe4145386c7d14ee7cac5_par594534bd98ef448ce38e1b09c49dc3dd.jpeg)

Comment: Ну видишь, тут тоже спорно, так как я просил, без лишних регистраций...Может уже имеет какой то двиг или скрипт?!